# Visual Studio 2019 Team Explorer missing GitHub option panels

Tags: visual-studio

So I just installed VS 2019 and right of the box, I am not seeing the options for Github as I can see on 2017.

Here is what I am seeing:
[image]

I am expecting to see this:
[image]

What could cause the options not showing up?  I can see them on VS 2017.  TIA.

Answer (score 5):

To Solve this problem we need to simply disabled  New Git user experience option. To do so, press "**Ctrl+Q**"(to search) -> now paste **preview features** -> uncheck  **New Git user experience** checkbox. And Wala! you are done!
For more information check this link=> [enter link description here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/improved-git-experience-in-visual-studio-2019/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20enable%20or%20disable,the%20New%20Git%20user%20experience.)
This is the way I solved my Problem.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this issue. I went to the Search box at the very top of Visual Studio, looked for **preview features** as mentioned in another comment, and unchecked **New Git user experience**. That reverted it to the old way. Then, I went back and checked it back on, and the *Git Changes tab* reappeared in the solution explorer window.

Answer (score 0):

Something changed recently with an update to VS 2019. If you click the "Open Git Changes" link, it opens a new window that lets you do the individual Fetch, Pull and Push operations (highlighted arrows screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1E3h.png)).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, git was moved to a menu option "Git" in Visual Studio 2019 16.8.3. Maybe I am missing something but I can have a go and try the new menu *Git* > *Manage Branches*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just have the same problem that i was missing the "Team Explorer" Panel (Changes, Sync etc.)in Visual Studio 2019.

When I was turning off following Option, the menu was looking like VS2017:
Git -> Options -> Environment -> Preview Feature

Turning off "New git user experience" Option.

Maybe this helps.

Here the article about the "New git user experience":
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/exciting-new-updates-to-the-git-experience-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, suddenly when I opened my Visual Studio 2019 Professional Edition, the Git connection is gone in Team Explorer, and I can't even see my projects in Azure Devops when I am already connected.

My solution is I just updated my Visual Studio by checking for new updates by going on Help Menu -> Check for Updates.

[image]